# PHP mailer form with radio buttons using AJAX to send

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, phpmailer, mailer

**TL; DR Solution:** change .val in the javascript to .serialize for any radio inputs.

I've been using [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/) to build a form that, when the submit button is pressed, fades out the button and fades in a "thanks" message and sends the mailer.php in the background.  My form has radio buttons and I cannot seem to figure out how to get the javascript to send which button was selected through to my email.

Here's the form html:

```
<form action="" method="" name="rsvp" id="rsvp-form">
<fieldset>
                <legend>RSVP</legend>

                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <input id="accepts1" class="rsvps" name="rsvps" type="radio" value="Graciously_Accepts" />
                            <label for="accepts1">Graciously Accepts</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input id="declines1" class="rsvps" name="rsvps" type="radio" value="Regretfully_Declines" />
                            <label for="declines1">Regretfully Declines</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input id="accepts2" class="rsvps" name="rsvps" type="radio" value="Regretfully_Accepts" />
                            <label for="accepts2">Regretfully Accepts</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input id="declines2" class="rsvps" name="rsvps" type="radio" value="Graciously_Declines" />
                            <label for="declines2">Graciously Declines</label>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
            </fieldset>
<div id="rsvp-wrapper">
    <fieldset>
     <button class="button" type="submit" value="send">RSVP!</button>
</fieldset>

</form>
<div class="success"></div>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {  

$(".button").click(function() {  

var rsvps = $(".rsvps").val();

var dataString = 'rsvps=' + rsvps;  

    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "rsvp-mailer.php",  
      data: dataString,  
      success: function() {  
        $('#rsvp-wrapper').html("<div class='success'></div>");  
        $('.success').html("<p class='italic'>Thanks!</p>")   
        .hide()  
        .fadeIn(500, function() {  
          $('.success');  
        });  
      }  
    });  
    return false;   
});  
});  

</script>
```

And the mailer.php:

```
<?php 

$rsvps = $_POST['rsvps'];

$formcontent="

RSVP: $rsvps \n";

$recipient = "myemail@domain.com";

$subject = "RSVP";

$mailheader = "RSVP \r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

?>
```

Thank you so much for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try. See [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for more info.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.post("rsvp-mailer.php", data, function() {
            $('#rsvp-wrapper').html("<div class='success'></div>");  
            $('.success').html("<p class='italic'>Thanks!</p>")   
            .hide()  
            .fadeIn(500, function() {  
                $('.success');  
            });  
        }

    return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes!, this is the best way to send all the form in order and later you call any element name on other page.. and display the result as you whish.. hope this works good for you.

Comment: This is returning the correct data, but in the url of the page, not an email.  E.G: domain.com/?rsvps=Regretfully_Declines

Comment: Turns out just changing .val to .serialize worked.  The only small issue is that in the email it says `RSVP: rsvps=Regretfully_Declines`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than accessing the radio button via a class selector, try the following:

```
var rsvps = $('input[name=rsvps]:radio').val();
```

Comment: When I do that it just sends me the first radio button as a response, even though another radio has been selected.

Comment: Actually taking your snippet and changing .val to .serialize worked.  The only small issue is that in the email it says `RSVP: rsvps=Regretfully_Declines`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript to get the values in order for them to be sent to the email. Use PHP instead.

```
   $formcontent .= $_POST['rsvp'];
```

That line will added before $recipient should send the value of the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

change `var rsvps = $(".rsvps").val();` to `var rsvps = $(".rsvps[selected=selected]").val();`

Also, dataString needs to be a json object like this `var dataString = { rsvps : rsvps };` to be accessible via ajax POST.